# How to specify time-range relative to latest data instead of relative to today or fixed date in Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

Data is imported not continuously but every now and then. I would like some charts do display data of the last week with last not meaning last seven days from now, but last seven days from maximum time in data. Is that possible (without a virtual dataset)? I could solve this with a virtual dataset but prefer a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior by using Custom SQL in `Filters`. You can filter based on a subquery from same or another table's max timestamp.
Example:
[image]